# GCP us-east1 increase vCPU above 24

Tags: virtual-machines, google-cloud-platform

Just started on GCP, trying to create a VM, chose "custom" and set vCPU to 48, it fails to create because there is a quota limit at 24 vCPUs for us-east1. There is a button that says "Request Increase", I clicked it. Do I now have to wait?

I see a Quotas tab, there is an "Edit" button, but I cannot edit the us-east1 entry (or any entry). Is there some way I can increase the quota?

I'm unsure what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do need to request a resource quota increase. If your account is brand-new with no activity history and record of good account standing, it is unlikely they would. Although you can certainly try.

To request a quota increase, follow the below steps:

1. Go to the Quotas page.
2. In the Quotas page, select the quotas you want to change.
3. Click the Edit Quotas button on the top of the page.
4. Check the box of the service you want to edit.
5. Fill out your name, email, and phone number, and click Next.
6. Enter your request to increase your quota, and click Next.
7. Submit your request.

A support representative from the Compute Engine team will respond to your request within 24 to 48 hours.

Note: If your account is under [free trail](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier#free-trial), you cannot request for a quota change. This is explained under the '[Program Coverage](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier#free-trial)' option. In this situation, you need to [upgrade your account](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier#how-to-upgrade) first, before making such requests.

https://cloud.google.com/compute/quotas

Comment: Once I upgraded my account from "trial" to "full", I was able to edit the boxes as you described, and submit the request.